# haskell regex replace: pattern contains backslash

Tags: regex, haskell

I want to replace a latex command into a character by using regex in Haskell

I tried to do the following regex replacement in ghci:

```
> putStrLn $ 
    subRegex (mkRegex "(\\mbfA)([^[:alnum:]])") "\\mbfA \\mbfAlpha" "o\\2"
```

and get this result:

```
\o \mbfAlpha
```

This is not what I want, what I want to get is `o \mbfAlpha`.

In Python, I can get what I want:

```
In [7]: print(re.sub(r"(\\mbfA)(\W)", "o\\2", "\\mbfA \\mbfAlpha"))
o \mbfAlpha
```

Is there any ways in Haskell that I can do string replacement with a regex containing backslash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your python, you've got a *raw string*: `r"(\\mbfA)(\W)"` - which means that a backslash is just a backslash, not an escape character.

In your Haskell code however, you will need to escape backslashes with backslashes, an when you need a double backslash in the regex, you will need four backslashes in the string. This should work therefore:

```
makeRegex "(\\\\mbfA)([^[:alnum:]])" :: Regex
```